# adding type information without dependency on typing module

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, typeshed

I have been adding type information to my package's `.py` files in order to support running `mypy` against the package. Among other things allows to generate [typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed) information for this, third party, package.

Since my package has to be Python 2.7 compatible, I use comments for the type information:

```
def __init__(self, s):
    # type: (Text) -> None
```

but in order to run `mypy` this requires me to import typing:

```
from typing import Text, IO, BinaryIO, Union
```

this causes two problems:

1. This will not work on Python 3.5.0 and 3.5.1 as it has a module `typing` but that doesn't include `Text`. Installing [`typing`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/typing) from PyPI doesn't solve that. (And there are users that run the package on that version of Python).
2. This make my package dependent on [`typing`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/typing) for 2.7/3.3/3.4 installs, requiring extra downloads and installs.
3. I have my own `Union` types defined:

   ```
   StreamType = Union[BinaryIO, IO[str], StringIO]
   StreamTextType = Union[Text, StreamType]
   ```

   the code for this would have to be conditionally executed depending on typing being available or not.

For the first problem, since I do not run `mypy` under Python 3.5.0/1, I can do something like:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info < (3, 5, 0) and sys.version_info >= (3, 5, 2):
    from typing import Text, IO, BinaryIO, Union
```

but that doesn't solve the second issue.

Commenting out the `import`, like the type information that is in comments,

```
# from typing import Text, IO, BinaryIO, Union
```

will cause `mypy` to throw an error `Name 'Text' is not defined`.

The third issue can be solve by using a `try`-`except` (ugly, and maybe also inefficient) or e.g. by testing against an environment variable (which could also be used to solve the first problem).

Is there an environment variable set when running `mypy`, that I can test against, so that the import statement is only executed when running `mypy`? 
Testing against an environment variable would also allow me to put the definition of my own types within that "guarded".

Or some other solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only environment variable associated with `mypy` is `MYPYPATH` and that is read by the package's code, and not set by it. Although `MYPYPATH` might be set (especially when generating `typeshed` information, to provide the "other" type info), there is no guarantee that it is.

You cannot comment out the `import` statement, but you **can** put it in a block that never executes:

```
if False:  # MYPY
    from typing import Text, IO, BinaryIO, Union
```

this has the advantage that you don't have to import `os` to get at the environment variable (and/or `sys` to get at the `version_info`) if you have no other need for that in your specific Python file.

Your type definitions should be specified like that as well, and can occur anywhere after all of the used types have been imported or defined:

```
# import or define StringIO

if False:  # MYPY
    StreamType = Union[BinaryIO, IO[str], StringIO]
    StreamTextType = Union[Text, StreamType]
```

If the above is in `mytypes.py`, any other source file in your package, using `StreamTypeText` in any of the type definitions, should do:

```
if False:  # MYPY
    from typing import Text, IO, BinaryIO, Union
    from .mytypes StreamType
```

*The above will satisfy `mypy`, so it will not throw an error on `Text` not being defined. It will also work on 3.5.0/1 and obliviates the need for making your package dependent on `typing`*

You would probably still have to install `typing` if you were to run `mypy` in a Python 2.7 environment, but your normal package's users are not affected by that.

Note that I added a comment `# MYPY` after the `if` of each block. Searching files for `from typing` is easy, but the block with `StreamType` would otherwise not so easily be found, in case `mypy` changes its behaviour and your code needs adapting.